# Automatically Email Col3 When Col10 to Col12 are Updated (Google Sheets)

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Afternoon!

I'm attempting to write a script that automatically sends an email of the value in Col3 when the corresponding value (same row) in Columns 10 to 12 are edited. Ideally, it would not send an email in regards to Col11 or Col12 if Col10 is already filled, but that would be icing on the cake. Attached is the script I was originally trying to build off of (ripped from a google search) - however, I don't need a customizable email body, just the value of Col3.

```
function sendEmailByRow(row)
{
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,row,4).getValues();
  var row_values = values[0];
  
  var mail = composeApprovedEmail(row_values);
  
  //Uncomment this line for testing
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" subject is "+mail.subject+"\n message "+mail.message);
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(admin_email,mail.subject,mail.message);
  
  var candidate_email = composeCandidateEmail(row_values);
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(candidate_email.email,candidate_email.subject,candidate_email.message);
}

function composeCandidateEmail(row_values)
{
  var first_name = row_values[0];
  
  var last_name = row_values[1];
  
  var email = row_values[2];

  var message = "The following applicant is approved: "+first_name+" "+last_name+
    " email "+email;
  var subject = first_name+ ", Your appliation is approved";
  
  var message = "Hello "+first_name+"\n"+
    "Your application is approved.\n Please follow the following instructions to proceed with the process.\n";
    //... etc
     
  return({message:message,subject:subject, email:email });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the maximum time for beginning to edit column10 and completing editing column 12

Comment: It could be weeks between when Col10 and Col12 are updated, but it could also be a matter of days, too inconsistent to use a time based trigger

Comment: I was not considering timebased triggers.

Comment: You need to store two dates for each item.  At first you put the current date into all of the old dates and then wait until all of the new dates get filled in and every time the new dates are all filled in then you send an email and reset all three of the old dates to the current date and leave the new date  empty. I would do it with an onEdit

Comment: It would be great if you can share the spreadsheet with the current script you are working on so I can replicate. Remember to remove sensitive information.